# Why Python needs two storage blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory-management

Why list in Python needs two storage blocks?

[List is stored in two blocks of memory (One is fixed-sized and the other is variable-sized for storing data)](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/tuples-vs-list-in-python)

Is it because one block stores the root address and the other one is to keep track of the dynamic changes of the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Splitting lists into a fixed-size metadata header and a variable-size data buffer lets the data buffer be reallocated without invalidating pointers other code is holding, since other code only holds pointers to the metadata header.